# Dialog dispose behavior on IOS, lockup on re-entry second+ time

Tags: codenameone

My OS is Windows 10 Pro,
IDE: Netbeand 12.2,
Simulator is latest:

Issue is lockup in Dialog on second+ instantiation within same Form instance IOS Only.
Simulator and Android behaves as expected.

Very strange behavior.
Within a Form I click a button to instantiate a Class (A1MMASiteMeterReadDialog) of type Dialog, I pass in some Vectors of Data and perform Tasks. When Finished we execute dispose() on this.

**a1SiteMeterReadDialog = new A1MMASiteMeterReadDialog(a1MMAHomePage, res, inc);**

User can re-enter this Class (A1MMASiteMeterReadDialog) multiple times if they have not finished all tasks.

**On IOS Only**, re-entering a second+ time, the class appears unstable, some TextFields do not behave correctly and do not respond to the ActionListener, eventually after a few more operations in this instance, the App locks up.
Codename1 logs and Native logs do not reveal anything, no sign of an exception thrown.
Have to forcefully stop the app and restart it.

Very strange.

I am wondering if the dispose() on IOS behaves differently on IOS than Android or simulator.
Or is IOS holding a reference to the first instance of the class and re instantiating the class is not clean and explain the unstable behavior.

I have spent nearly 2 weeks working on this and am no closer to a solution.
Any Thoughts on this would be appreciated?

Regards

Comment: I'll need a way to reproduce this to give a better answer. If you can reproduce this on xcode and crash it consistently there might be a specific native stack that might point at something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

`dispose()` behaves the same but text input is very different so it's possible something is misbehaving on that sense. In general we recommend avoiding text input in `Dialog` classes as it's pretty problematic.